# Why is creating a List in C# causing this error?

Tags: c#, list, compiler-errors

While trying to create a simple list within C# I am getting the following error:
'The feature 'top-level statements' is currently in Preview and *unsupported*. To use Preview features, use the 'preview' language version. [5.1]'

At this point the only code I have entered is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

List<string> stringList = new List<string>();
```

Why would I be directed towards using a Preview version of C#, surely lists have been in use for a while?

Comment: You're trying to write code outside a class.

Comment: there´s no such thing as a "global" concept in .NET. Everything relates to **classes**, which build the fundament of OOP. So while lists are supported in .NET from the very beginning, variables outside a class are something that is under development.

Comment: The above scenario (Top Level Programs) is supported in C# 9 only, which is currently a preview feature. It is scheduled to be released in the coming November.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you recieve is not about **lists**, but about **scopes**. So the answer to

> surely lists have been in use for a while?

is a definitive "yes". Lists (or at least arrays) exists since the very beginnings of C#, while generics followed in C# 2.0 which was supported from VS2005 onwards (for more information about the C# language-history see https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-version-history).

Your problem however is that you have a statement outside a class. However classes are the very fundamental concept behind OOP - everything relates to classes. The following - which has nothing to do with lists - would also be invalid:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

int i = 3;
```

As mentioned before everything in .NET relates to classes - there´s no such conceptional thing as "global". So you have to move your statement into a class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class MyClass
{
    List<string> stringList = new List<string>();
}
```

This will scope your list to a specific instance of `MyClass`. You can further limit the scope of a variable to a method or even a specific scope within a method. For further information about scopes read [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c-sharp/).

After all the error-message you recieve relates to a new feature that is [under discussion for C#9](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/top-level-statements):

> Allow a sequence of statements to occur right before the
> namespace_member_declarations of a compilation_unit (i.e. source
> file).

Answer (score 2):

You can't just initialize a variable at the top level, it needs to be enclosed in a class if it's a member E.g.:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    List<string> stringList = new List<string>();
}
```

Or inside a method if it's a local variable

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<string> stringList = new List<string>();
    }
}
```